# hide td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i want to hide table columns. On load of page hide 2nd columns of every options. On selection of `email me` option, show the 2nd column. If i select 2nd `call me` option, then hide 1st one and show column 2 of 2nd call me option. I don't know how to do in jquery.

2)  also if i select 1st option then 2nd option then that time both  option is selected, i dont want these. i want it randomly. can anybody tell me..

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="radio" value="email" name="select" id="emailbtn" onClick="showemail()" />
            </td>
            <td valign="top">Email me</td>
            <td class="td1" style="display:none;">
                <input type="email" placeholder="*************" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" size="50" class="snk12" id="email_id" required/>
                <br />
                <p id="imgparent">
                    <div id="imgdiv" style="float:left;">
                        <img id="img" src="captcha.php" />
                    </div>
                    <img id="reload" style="float:left;" src="reload.png" />
                </p>
                <input id="captcha1" name="captcha" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type='submit' value="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<form name="form2" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="radio" value="call" name="select" id="callbtn" onClick="showphn()" />
            </td>
            <td valign="top">Call Me</td>
            <td class="td2" style="display:none;">
                <input type="text" class="snk12" size="50" required pattern="[0-9]{10}$" name="phn" id="call" placeholder="*************" />
                <br />
                <p id="imgparent">
                    <div id="imgdiv" style="float:left;">
                        <img id="img" src="captcha.php" />
                    </div>
                    <img id="reload" style="float:left;" src="reload.png" />
                </p>
                <input id="captcha1" name="captcha" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type='submit' value="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: And what YOU did so far with jquery ?

Comment: hey i got the solution but can u tell me why both redio buttons are selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can show / hide elements using jQuery by `$('selector').hide()` or `$('selector').show()`, where selector is either a DOM element or a .class or an #id.

You can also apply CSS selectors like `$('element:nth-child(1)').hide()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sandysharma What keeps you from using Google to at least learn the very basics of jQuery?